# Strings with HTML font styles from external DB

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi, guys! I'm working on app which uses a external sqlite database . I'm using a sample source code and I would like to some excerpts from the entries present bold or italic style or a different color.

For example, if I have an entry like this: **Black** is my favorite color. I would like my string recognize the HTML tags. The word "black" in my example should be in bold.

I'm a newbie and I need a help in details. This is my code:

WordView.java

```
public class WordView extends TextView implements OnTouchListener {

private PopupView popup;
private String infoWord;
private ScrollView parent;
private boolean mClickEnabled;
private Typeface transTypeFace, transTypeFaceBold;
private static final Map<String, String[]> FONTS = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
static {
    FONTS.put("sans", new String[] { "DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf", "DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf"});
    FONTS.put("serif", new String[] { "DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf", "DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf"});
}

private class Type1Span extends ClickableSpan {
    String word;
    public Type1Span(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(touchedInstance == this);
        ds.setTypeface(transTypeFace);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        if (mClickEnabled) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("ecidiomas://" + word);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            widget.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};

private class Type2Span extends Type1Span {
    public Type2Span(String word) {
        super(word);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setTypeface(transTypeFaceBold);
    }
}

private class TranscriptionTypeSpan extends ForegroundColorSpan {
    public TranscriptionTypeSpan(int color) {
        super(color);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setTypeface(transTypeFaceBold);
        //ds.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    }
}

private Type1Span touchedInstance;

public WordView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public WordView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public WordView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Context ctx = getContext();
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    String defaultType = "sans";
    String fontType = sp.getString(App.PreferenceKeys.preference_font_idx, defaultType);
    if (!FONTS.containsKey(fontType)) fontType = defaultType;
    transTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), FONTS.get(fontType)[0]);
    transTypeFaceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), FONTS.get(fontType)[1]);
    setTypeface(transTypeFaceBold);
    setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    ViewParent p = getParent();
    if (p instanceof ScrollView)
        parent = (ScrollView) p;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ?
            true : super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setWordInfo(String word, String translation, String text) {
    infoWord = word;
    translation = translation.trim();
    translation = TextUtils.isEmpty(translation) ? "" : (translation + '\n');
    setText(infoWord.trim().toUpperCase() + "\n" + translation + "\n"+ text);
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    Integer currentType = LinksFinder.getType(infoWord != null ? infoWord : ""); //XXX
    ArrayList<LinksFinder.LinkSpec> links = LinksFinder.getLinks(text.toString());
    if (links == null) {
        super.setText(text, type);
        return;
    }
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
    int links_length = links.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < links_length; ++i) {
        LinksFinder.LinkSpec l = links.get(i);
        CharacterStyle span;
        if (LinksFinder.TRANSCRIPTION == l.type) {
            span = new TranscriptionTypeSpan(0xffc91111);
        } else if (currentType == l.type) {
            span = new Type2Span(l.url);
        } else {
            span = new Type1Span(l.url);
        }
        ss.setSpan(span, l.start, l.end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    super.setText(ss, type);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        x -= getTotalPaddingLeft();
        y -= getTotalPaddingTop();

        int xx = getRealPosX(x);
        int yy = getRealPosY(y);

        x += getScrollX();
        y += getScrollY();

        Layout layout = getLayout();
        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
        int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

        Type1Span[] candidates = ((Spannable) getText()).getSpans(off, off, Type1Span.class);
        if (candidates.length > 0) {
            touchedInstance = candidates[0];
        } else {
            touchedInstance = null;
        }
        if (mClickEnabled && popup != null && touchedInstance != null)
            popup.setPopupText(xx, yy, touchedInstance.word);
    } else {
        if (popup != null)
            popup.clear();
        if (touchedInstance != null) {
            touchedInstance = null;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void setPopup(PopupView popup) {
    this.popup = popup;
    this.popup.setTypeFace(transTypeFaceBold);
}

private int getRealPosX(int val) {
    return parent == null ? val : val - parent.getScrollX();
}

private int getRealPosY(int val) {
    return parent == null ? val : val - parent.getScrollY();
}

public void setClickEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mClickEnabled = enabled;
} 
}
```

WordAdapter.java

```
class WordAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable, DB {

private String[] QUERY_PROJECTION = new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_WORD };
private final int WORD_COLUMN_INDEX;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public WordAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super(context, c);
    WORD_COLUMN_INDEX = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_WORD);
    this.db = db;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
    view.setText(cursor.getString(WORD_COLUMN_INDEX));
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(WORD_COLUMN_INDEX));
}

@Override
public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
    return cursor.getString(WORD_COLUMN_INDEX);
}

@Override
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence s) {
    Cursor c = null;
    if (s != null)
        c = db.query(DB.TABLE_WORDS, QUERY_PROJECTION, getLike(s.toString().toLowerCase()), null, null, null, null);            
    return c;
}

private String getLike(String s) {
    return DB.COLUMN_WORD + ">= '" + s + "' AND " + DB.COLUMN_WORD + "< '" + s + '\u044F' +"'";
}

}
```